# iPhone loading screen until web request is finished

Tags: objective-c, loading, webrequest, appdelegate

I need to show "Loading screen" (just an image) at the start of application and when application gets all needed data from web, then first viewcontroller is shown. I have succeded doing it by setting my own black screen "Default.png" as "LoadingScreen.png" (Of course named again as Default.png) and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[THWViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"THWViewController" bundle:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

- (void)start
{
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}
```

I would change that random delay to when api loading is finished, but is this a good way of implementing it ? Because i get that message that rootviewcontroller is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a block so you can eliminate that random delay.  I would also consider calling this from your first view rather than starting with no root (remove the warning):

```
//show your loading screen over your first view
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Get all the needed data

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do what you need to do with data and in first view
        //hide the loading screen
    });
});
```